# Village running on bitcoin tech

Tags: community

I would like to find out if anybody knows or has experience using Bitcoins to run the internal finances for a community ?

Answer (score 1):

Liberland: Europe’s Newly Formed Country to Use Bitcoin
Read Full article

http://insidebitcoins.com/news/liberland-europes-newly-formed-country-to-use-bitcoin/31979

On April 13, 2015 the Free Republic of Liberland was officially formed by a group of Czech citizens. The newly formed country of Liberland is a three square mile plot of land between Serbia and Croatia. The President of Liberland, Vit Jedlicka, has confirmed that Liberland will not have an official currency nor a printed currency. The country will however, accept all currencies, both bitcoin and other digital currencies.

The Free Republic of Liberland, or “Liberland”, is only the size of three square miles, situated between Serbia and Croatia. The west bank of the Danube river runs alongside its border. This area between Croatia and Serbia had previously been declared terra nullius or a no man’s land. On April 13, 2015 the land was officially claimed and given its name after the Preparatory Committee declared the new state and raised a flag on location.